# How to reference variables in other classes

Tags: java, reference, instance-variables

I just feel like I'm not doing this correctly and I have researched and just can't seem to wrap my head around how to initialize variable that have to reference another method or class.

Player class

```
public class Player
{
   //instance variables
   private String name;
   private ScoreCard card;
   private int fullDriveYards;
   private int fullDrives;
   private int drivesOnTarget;
}
```

Here's the ScoreCard class variables

```
public class ScoreCard
{
    private int totalStrokes;
    private int versusPar;
    private LinkedList<Integer> playerScoreCard;
}
```

So this is how I have initialized the instance variables is Player class I did not code the Scorecard class as I didn't have to but I still added it so you can see what's going on. I just need to know if I am on the right track or completely off.

```
// Constructor for objects of class Player
public Player(String PlayerName)
{
       // initialize all instance variables
       // look for and handle a null reference for playerName
       // to initialize this.card create ScoreCard instance and assign reference
       this.name = PlayerName;
       PlayerName = "UNKNOWN";
       ScoreCard card = this.card;
       this.card = new ScoreCard();
       this.longestDrive = 0;
       this.fullDriveYards = 0;
       this.fullDrives = 0;
       this.drivesOnTarget = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I just feel like I'm not doing this correctly ..."*

It's correct, there are just some inconsistencies, so you may not get the result you're looking for.

In your constructor method for *Player*, you are assigning *PlayerName* to the *name* field, and then subsequently assigning *PlayerName* to *"UNKNOWN"*.

Assigning *PlayerName* will have no effect on *name*.

```java
this.name = PlayerName;
PlayerName = "UNKNOWN";
```

In your comment you mention,

```java
// look for and handle a null reference for playerName
```

You'll need a *conditional statement* for this.

```java
if (PlayerName == null) PlayerName = "UNKNOWN";
this.name = PlayerName;
```

Furthermore, you are assigning your class variable *card* to a new local variable *card*.

This, again, will have no effect, since *this.card* would be *null* at this point.

```java
// to initialize this.card create ScoreCard instance and assign reference
```

The following will suffice.

```java
this.card = new ScoreCard();
```

So, the complete constructor should look like the following.

```java
public Player(String PlayerName)
{
    // initialize all instance variables
    // look for and handle a null reference for playerName
    // to initialize this.card create ScoreCard instance and assign reference
    if (PlayerName == null) PlayerName = "UNKNOWN";
    this.name = PlayerName;
    this.card = new ScoreCard();
    this.longestDrive = 0;
    this.fullDriveYards = 0;
    this.fullDrives = 0;
    this.drivesOnTarget = 0;
}
```

> *"... I have researched and just can't seem to wrap my head around how to initialize variable that have to reference another method or class. ..."*

You're assignment is correct,

```java
this.card = new ScoreCard();
```

Since you're *ScoreCard* class variables are declared as *private*, you won't be able to access them via *dot-notation*—e.g., *card.totalStrokes*.

You will need to either remove the modifier, change the modifier to *public*, or create methods that will provide the access.

```java
public class ScoreCard
{
    private int totalStrokes;
    private int versusPar;
    private LinkedList<Integer> playerScoreCard;

    public int getTotalStrokes() {
        return totalStrokes;
    }

    public void setTotalStrokes(int totalStrokes) {
        this.totalStrokes = totalStrokes;
    }

    public int getVersusPar() {
        return versusPar;
    }

    public void setVersusPar(int versusPar) {
        this.versusPar = versusPar;
    }

    public LinkedList<Integer> getPlayerScoreCard() {
        return playerScoreCard;
    }

    public void setPlayerScoreCard(LinkedList<Integer> playerScoreCard) {
        this.playerScoreCard = playerScoreCard;
    }
}
```

Then, you can access the values as follows.

```java
card.setTotalStrokes(123);
card.setVersusPar(123);
card.setPlayerScoreCard(new LinkedList<>());
```

Here are some references by *Java* which may help in your coding process.

*[Classes (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html).*
*[Lesson: Object-Oriented Programming Concepts (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).*

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong with the intialization.

- didn't handle a null player name.
- Assigned an uninitialized `ScoreCard` to a local card variable. Didn't really hurt anything but it is redundant and that value of card will go out of scope when the constructor is finished.

Check if the player is null or has a blank name (including being empty). Note you **must** check if `playerName` is null first before attempting to check if it is blank. Otherwise, you may get a null pointer exception if the playerName is null.

For the score card, just assign the card an instance of `ScoreCard`. It is presumed some of your player methods will modify the scorecard as needed by simply using the field `card`.

```
// Constructor for objects of class Player
public Player(String PlayerName)
{
       // initialize all instance variables
       // look for and handle a null reference for playerName
       // to initialize this.card create ScoreCard instance and assign reference
      
       if (playerName == null || playerName.isBlank()) {
            this.name = "UNKNOWN";
       } else {
           this.name = playerName;
       }
       this.card = new ScoreCard();
       this.longestDrive = 0;
       this.fullDriveYards = 0;
       this.fullDrives = 0;
       this.drivesOnTarget = 0;
}
```